# Unable to load Angular2 CLI production build from a remote package

Tags: angular, systemjs

I'm trying to load an angular package from a remote CDN URL. The angular assets are compiled w/ the angular CLI using the -prod flag.

```
ng build -prod
```

The following is from the system-config file in the host application (`http://localhost:4200`).

```
{
  map: {'sharedcomponent':'http://mycdn.com/shared-component'}
  packages: {
    "http://mycdn.com/shared-component": {
      "main": "main.js",
      "meta": {
        "*": {
          "format": "system",
          "scriptLoad": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The host application is later importing the component returns an empty object.

```
System.import('sharedcomponent')
  .then(function(comp){
    console.log(comp); //outputs {}
  });
```

When inspecting `SystemJS.defined` in the console, I can see all the bundled modules loaded under the 'localhost:4200' domain rather than the CDN domain.

However if I deploy a non bundled build, every thing loads correctly.

Can anyone provide any insight? Is this an issue w/ the systemjs or the angular CLI?

Answer (score 0):

After debugging through the SystemJS code, I was able to determine what the issue is.

When System.register is called, the module name will get resolved to an absolute URL using the System.decanonicalize method. That method uses the base url object instead of the URL of the package the bundled was loaded in.

The fix is to defer the name resolution until the reduce step where you have access to the loader.address property.

Luckily there are hooks in place that you can exploit to make the necessary changes.

After systemjs loads, I override the System.register function so that it doesn't decanonicalize the name.

```
System.register = function(name, deps, declare) {
  if (typeof name != 'string') {
    declare = deps; deps = name; name = null;
  }

  if (typeof declare == 'boolean')
    return this.registerDynamic.apply(this, arguments);

  this.pushRegister_({
    amd: false,
    entry: {
      name: name,
      deps: deps,
      declare: declare,
      declarative: true,
      executingRequire: false,
      esmExports: false,
      evaluated: false,
      originalIndices: null,
      execute: null,
      normalizedDeps: null,
      groupIndex: null,
      module: null,
      esModule: null
    }
  });
};
```

I then override the reduceRegister_ function to look for a metadata flag to determine if the decanonicalize method should be used to resolve the module name.

If it is set to false, I simply resolve the name using the load.address vs. the base URL object.

```
System.reduceRegister_ = function(load, register){
  if (register) {
    let entry = register && register.entry;
    entry.name = (load.metadata && load.metadata.decanonicalize === false) ?
      new URL(entry.name, load.address).href.replace(/%05/g, '#') :
      this.decanonicalize(entry.name, load.address);
  }
  this.__proto__.reduceRegister_.call(this, load, register);
}
```

The package configuration is here:

```
{
  map: {'sharedcomponent':'http://mycdn.com/shared-component'}
  packages: {
    "http://mycdn.com/shared-component": {
      "main": "main.js",
      "meta": {
        "*": {
          "format": "system",
          "scriptLoad": true,
          "decanonicalize":false
      }
    }
  }
```